# Using SecurityIdentifier Class's translate method to find domain names from SID

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to resolve foreignSecurityPrincipal objects to user, computer and group objects. I've found that I can use the translate method from the SecurityIdentifier class to resolve the SID to the NTAccount value which is 'NetBIOSName\username'.The problem is this isn't the full domain name. I need the DNSRoot name or some other property I can extract the domain name from such as the user's distinguishedName or the CanonicalName. Is there any way I can use the translate method to accomplish this? or some other method I could use?

```
(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($Sid)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
```

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Convert-Foreign-Security-1fdbaf46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Translate()` method returns an [`IdentityReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.identityreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object. The only property of that object (`Value`) gives you the string value of the translated identity.

`(Get-ADDomain -Identity 'DOMAIN').DNSroot` might give you what you're looking for, though.

---

If the NetBIOS domain name is too unspecific you could try something like this:

- Get a list of your forest root domains.
- Enumerate its domains of each forest.
- Extract the [domain-specific part](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962011.aspx) of each domain SID.
- Build a hashtable from the SID parts and FQDNs.

```bsh
$forest  = 'foo.example.org'
$domains = @{}
Get-ADForest $forest |
    Select-Object -Expand Domains |
    Get-ADDomain |
    ForEach-Object {
        $domains[($_.DomainSID.Value -replace '^S-\d+-\d+-')] = $_.DNSRoot
    }
```

With that hashtable you should be able to look up the user domains by their user SID:

```
$userdomain = $domains[($sid -replace '^S-\d+-\d+-(.*?)-\d+$', '$1')]
```

Comment: Can you provide the synatx for what this would look like in PowerShell?

Comment: (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($Sid)).Translate() 

I'm assuming this is what you were referring to? the () doesn't work as there are no constructors that match that argument set. Forgive me I'm very new to using .net within PowerShell.

Comment: `Translate()` as shown in your question already gave you a string with a (NetBIOS) domain and username. Split the string and use the NetBIOS domain name with `Get-ADDomain` as shown in my answer.

Comment: oh I see, I went down that path. The problem I ran into however, was it doesn't provide enough of the domain name. We have several forests and some use the same netbios but different root domain names example America\Domain1 America\Domain2 and because of that I wanted to somehow get the FQND so I could look up the object with ad-adobject -server FQND. Perhaps the best solution is to do as you said and to a try catch block on all the trusts within the domain.

Comment: One thing you could do would be to enumerate all domains in all forests, get their domain SIDs, and match the domain-specific portion of the user SID against those.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following function:

```
function Get-DomainFromSid($Sid){
    $domain = $null
    try{
        $objectSid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($Sid)
        $domain = Get-ADDomain -Identity $objectSid.AccountDomainSid | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DNSRoot
    }    
    catch{
        Write-Verbose "Failed to get domain from Sid"
    }
    return $domain
}
```